# How to generate cumulative unique count at a group level in python?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas-groupby, cumulative-sum, cumulative-frequency

I have some hospital visit healthcare data in a dataframe of the form:

| record_id | client_id | date_of_encounter | hospital_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MK456 | 2014-01-01 | 01J |
| 2 | JJ103 | 2016-04-01 | 02J |
| 3 | MK456 | 2014-02-26 | 01J |
| 4 | JJ103 | 2016-05-01 | 02H |
| 5 | MK456 | 2014-03-01 | 02H |
| 6 | JJ103 | 2016-06-06 | 02J |

I want to create a column `hospital_count` which is a cumulative count of the UNIQUE hospitals visits by each client at the `date_of_counter`. I have already sorted is by the `client_id` and
`date_of_counter`. The result transformation would be

| record_id | client_id | date_of_encounter | hospital_id | hospital_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MK456 | 2014-01-01 | 01J | 1 |
| 3 | MK456 | 2014-02-26 | 01J | 1 |
| 5 | MK456 | 2014-03-01 | 02H | 2 |
| 2 | JJ103 | 2016-04-01 | 02J | 1 |
| 4 | JJ103 | 2016-05-01 | 02H | 2 |
| 6 | JJ103 | 2016-06-06 | 02J | 2 |

Some suggest using a combination of a `groupby` and `cumsum()` but I am not too sure how?

Comment: I think you're looking for [`GoupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-cumcount) rather than `cumsum`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`GoupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-cumcount)

**Cumulative count of the number of distinct hospitals visited by each client**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'record_id': list(range(1,7)),
  'client_id':['MK', 'JJ', 'MK', 'JJ', 'MK', 'JJ'],
  'date': [20140101, 20160401,20140226,20160501,20140301,20160606],
  'hospital': ['1j', '2j', '1j', '2h', '2h', '2j']
})

df.sort_values(by=['client_id', 'date'], inplace=True)

df['hospital_count'] = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['client_id', 'hospital']
  ).groupby('client_id').cumcount() + 1

df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

print(df)
#    record_id client_id      date hospital  hospital_count
# 1          2        JJ  20160401       2j             1.0
# 3          4        JJ  20160501       2h             2.0
# 5          6        JJ  20160606       2j             2.0
# 0          1        MK  20140101       1j             1.0
# 2          3        MK  20140226       1j             1.0
# 4          5        MK  20140301       2h             2.0
```

Explanation: We drop successive visits of the same client to the same hospital using `drop_duplicates`; then we can simply count the visits of each client using `groupby` and `cumcount`. However, this leaves `NaN` values in the lines that were dropped; we fill those values using `fillna`.

**Cumulative count of the number of visits of each client to each hospital**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'record_id': list(range(1,7)),
  'client_id':['MK', 'JJ', 'MK', 'JJ', 'MK', 'JJ'],
  'date': [20140101, 20160401,20140226,20160501,20140301,20160606],
  'hospital': ['1j', '2j', '1j', '2h', '2h', '2j']
})

df['hospital_count'] = df.sort_values(by=['client_id', 'hospital', 'date']
  ).groupby(['client_id', 'hospital']
  ).cumcount() + 1

print(df)
#    record_id client_id      date hospital  hospital_count
# 0          1        MK  20140101       1j               1
# 1          2        JJ  20160401       2j               1
# 2          3        MK  20140226       1j               2
# 3          4        JJ  20160501       2h               1
# 4          5        MK  20140301       2h               1
# 5          6        JJ  20160606       2j               2
```

Comment: This does not provide the desired answer. Look at records 1, 3, 5 hospital counts

Comment: @Mazil_tov998 Ooooooooh, I misunderstood the question. I counted the number of times each client visited each hospital, not the number of different hospitals visited by each client.

Comment: @Mazil_tov998 Here is a new solution

Comment: @Mazil_tov998 Did I understand the solution correctly this time?

Comment: yes, it worked out correctly